# C++. How to create a function that will be remove specific lines in text file?

Tags: c++

im facing a real problem. Below I put my code that I did. What i should put into if
condition? Below also is my output and for example if user want to buy book "Solaris", 4 lines in file text about Solaris would be removed. I will be glad if someone help me.

```
plik - file
linia - line
tytulek - tittle of the book that user want to buy
biblioteka - library
indeks - index
tytul - title
data powstania - date
```

OUTPUT:

```
TytuÂł: Harry Potter
Indeks: 123
Autor: J.K Rowling
Data powstania: 1999 r.

TytuÂł: Władca Pierścien
Indeks: 888
Autor: J.R.R Tolkien
Data powstania: 567 r.

TytuÂł:  Solaris
Indeks: 555
Autor: Stanisław Lem
Data powstania: 1999 r.
```

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct ksiazka
{
    string tytul;
    string autor;
    int data;
    int indeks;
    float cena;

};
ksiazka baza[100];
int liczba_ksiazek=0;

void wprowadz();
void pokaz();
void pytanie();
void usun();


void intro()
{
    system("chcp 1250>>NULL");
    cout<<"Witaj w bibliotece! Wybierz jedn¹ z poni¿szych opcji wpisuj¹c cyfre (1-5)."<<endl;
}

int menu()
{
    system("chcp 1250>>NULL");
    int wybor;

    cout<<"(1) WprowadŸ ksi¹¿ki do biblioteki."<<endl;
    cout<<"(2) Poka¿ jakie s¹ obecnie ksi¹¿ki w bibliotce."<<endl;
    cout<<"(3) Kup ksi¹¿kê z biblioteki."<<endl;
    cout<<"(4) Wyjœcie."<<endl;
    cout<<"Co chcesz zrobiæ? Wpisz odpowiednią cyfrê: "<<endl;
    cin>>wybor;
    return wybor;

}

void choose(int wybor)
{
    if(wybor<1||wybor>4)
    {
        cout<<"WprowadŸ poprawn¹ liczbê (od 1 do 4)."<<endl<<endl;;;
        menu();
    }
    switch(wybor)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        wprowadz();
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        pokaz();
        break;
    }


    case 3:
    {
        usun();
        break;
    }



    case 4:
    {
        exit(0);
        break;
    }

    }




}







void wprowadz()
{
    int n;


    string tekst;

    ksiazka baza[100];
    cout<<"Podaj iloœæ ksi¹¿ek jak¹ chcesz wprowadziæ do biblioteki: ";
    cin>>n;

    fstream plik;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout<<"Podaj tytu³ ksi¹¿ki: ";
        getline(cin,baza[i].tytul);
        cout<<"Podaj imiê i nazwisko autora ksi¹¿ki: ";
        getline(cin,baza[i].autor);
        cout<<"Podaj datê powstania ksi¹zki: ";
        cin>>baza[i].data;
        cout<<"Podaj cenę książki: ";
        cin>>baza[i].cena;
        cout<<"Podaj 3-cyfrowy indeks ksi¹¿ki : ";
        cin>>baza[i].indeks;
        if ((baza[i].indeks)/100>=10||(baza[i].indeks)/100<1)
        {
            cout<<"Proszę podać 3-cyfrowy indeks: ";
            cin>>baza[i].indeks;
        }

        int k=1;


        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            if(baza[i].indeks==baza[i-k].indeks||baza[i].indeks==baza[i+k].indeks)
            {
                cout << "Podany indeks jest zajęty, podaj inny: ";
                cin>>baza[i].indeks;
            }

            k++;
        }




        plik.open("Biblioteka.txt",ios::out | ios::app);

        plik<<"Tytu³: "<<baza[i].tytul<<endl;
        plik<<"Indeks: "<<baza[i].indeks<<endl;
        plik<<"Autor: "<<baza[i].autor<<endl;
        plik<<"Data powstania: "<<baza[i].data<<" r."<<endl;
        plik<<"Cena: "<<baza[i].cena<<endl<<endl;


        plik.close();
    }


    pytanie();
}

    void usun()
    {
    
        string linia;
        int line;
        fstream plik;
        fstream temp;
        string usunieta;
        string tytulek;
        string x;
    
        int pozycja;
    
    
        cout<<"Podaj tytuł książki jaką chcesz kupić: ";
        cin>>tytulek;
        plik.open("biblioteka.txt",ios::out | ios::in );
        if (plik.is_open())
        {
            while ( getline (plik,x) )
            {
                if (x.find(tytulek, 0) != string::npos)
                {
                    {
                        pozycja=line;
                    }
    
                    line++;
                }
                plik.close();
            }
        }
    
    
    
    
        temp.open("temp.txt",ios::out);
        plik.open("biblioteka.txt",ios::out | ios::in );
        if (!plik.is_open())
        {
            cout << "\n\nNie można otworzyć pliku! "<<endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        while (getline (plik,linia))
        {
    
    
            int pos = linia.find(tytulek);
    
    
    
    
            if(    )
            {
                temp << linia << endl;
            }
        }
        plik.close();
        temp.close();
        remove("biblioteka.txt");
        rename("temp.txt","biblioteka.txt");
    
    
    
        pytanie();
        
    
    
    }
```

I tried almost everything.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250934/discussion-on-question-by-embape333-c-how-to-create-a-function-that-will-be-r). If you are asked for additional information, do not reply in the comments. Instead, [edit] the information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. It is very hard to understand you. So, maybe my answer is not adequate.

So, you want to remove a block of lines with book information from a file. Depending on the title.

What you need to add to your code is a condition (a boolean flag), when a line of text shall be written to the new file or when not.

And, because the book information consists of more lines, you need to count.

So, we need a boolean flage, for example `bool writeLine = true;` and a counter, for example `int numberOfLinesPerBookRecord = 0;`. Then you start your loop.

Then we need some logic to control the output of lines.

- First, we will check, if we are in mode "writeLine" and check, if we have found, what we were looking for
- If so, we goto mode "not writeLine" and set the number of lines to skip to 5
- if we are in "writeLine"-mode, we write the line to the new output file.
- if not, we do not write the line and decrement the "numberOfLinesPerBookRecord" counter.
- If this counter is 0, then we obviously skipped all necessary line, and go back to "writeLine" mode.

This could be implemented like in the belo example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // This is an example of a search string
    std::string tytulek = "Pierscien";

    // Open the source text file and a temporary file
    std::ifstream plik("biblioteka.txt");
    std::ofstream temp("temp.txt");

    // Check, if both are open
    if (plik and temp) {

        // Start in mode "write Line"
        bool writeLine = true;

        // This is for the number of lines to skip, in case we 
        // found a book that we want to omit
        int numberOfLinesPerBookRecord = 0;

        // Read all lines from the source file
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(plik, line)) {

            // If we are in normal mode and find a title containing the search string
            if ((not line.empty()) and writeLine and (line.length() > 6) and
                (line.substr(0, 6) == "Tytul:") and (line.find(tytulek) != std::string::npos)) {

                // Goto skip mode
                writeLine = false;
                // And we want to skip 5 lines
                numberOfLinesPerBookRecord = 5;
            }
            // If we are in normal mode, then simply write the just read line to the output file
            if (writeLine) {
                temp << line << '\n';
            }
            else {
                // If we are in skip mode, then skip 5 lines
                --numberOfLinesPerBookRecord;
                // After 5 lines were omitted, go back to normal mode
                if (numberOfLinesPerBookRecord == 0) {
                    writeLine = true;
                }
            }
        }
        plik.close();
        temp.close();
        std::remove("biblioteka.txt");
        std::rename("temp.txt", "biblioteka.txt");
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\n\nNie mozna otworzyc pliku!\n";
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Using this input file with ASCII characters (I cannot type something else):

```
Tytul: Harry Potter
Indeks: 123
Autor: J.K Rowling
Data powstania: 1999 r.

Tytul: Wladca Pierscien
Indeks: 888
Autor: J.R.R Tolkien
Data powstania: 567 r.

Tytul:  Solaris
Indeks: 555
Autor: Stanislaw Lem
Data powstania: 1999 r.
```

And the search string "Pierscien", again in ASCII.

produces this output in ASCII:

```
Tytul: Harry Potter
Indeks: 123
Autor: J.K Rowling
Data powstania: 1999 r.

Tytul:  Solaris
Indeks: 555
Autor: Stanislaw Lem
Data powstania: 1999 r.
```

I guess that is what you need

Comment: thanks for it but it still doesnt work. If user for example added 3 books (he had to write book details about that books)  then output can look like this:

 ~ TytuÂł: Harry Potter
Indeks: 123
Autor: J.K Rowling
Data powstania: 1999 r.
Cena: 20

TytuÂł: Władca Pierścien
Indeks: 888
Autor: J.R.R Tolkien
Data powstania: 567 r.
Cena: 20

TytuÂł:  Solaris
Indeks: 555
Autor: Stanisław Lem
Data powstania: 1999 r.
Cena: 20~

Comment: And when user want to buy a book, he types tittle of book he want to buy (this value is save in tytulek) all 5 lines that about that book will be removed from text file. For example when user typed Solaris, output would look like this:` TytuÂł: Harry Potter Indeks: 123 Autor: J.K Rowling Data powstania: 1999 r. Cena: 20 TytuÂł: Władca Pierścien Indeks: 888 Autor: J.R.R Tolkien Data powstania: 567 r. Cena: 20 `

Comment: The program works of course. Maybe you need to use a different character set. I can only test with ascii characters. So I compare against ""Tytul:". Maybe you need to change that to your language. Best to test everything with plain ASCII in the beginning. I cannot even type your characters. My question to you. Do you understand the code? If not, what do you not understand? Anyway. I will edit my answer and show you a demo.

Comment: Thank you, I have a question: what mean writeline in condition if? This mean that writeline has to be true?